# I am trying to create a like and dislike button for different posts on a page using JavaScript and Django but it seems to work first post only

Tags: javascript, html, django

For the most part, I've managed to create a thumbs up and thumbs down icon working as a like and dislike button, it increases and decreases the count as well for the FIRST POST ONLY, and whenever I click on a like button in any post beside the first post, the button doesn't toggle for that post, it toggles for the first post instead and shows count there. When I refresh the page, the count for other posts gets updated but the button never toggles.

**main.js**

```
function likeOnClick(id) {
    // $('#likes').click(function () {
        var postId;
        // postId = $('#likes').attr("data-postId");
        postId = id;
        console.log("I went inside the function", postId);
      

        var currentClass = $('#likes').attr('class');
        if (currentClass == 'fa fa-thumbs-up')
        {
         $("#likes").removeClass("fa fa-thumbs-up");   
            $("#likes").addClass("fa fa-thumbs-down");


            $.get('like_post/', { post_id: postId, ld: 'l' }, function (data) {
            $('#like_count').html(data);
            // $('#likes').hide();
        });

        }
        else{
            $("#likes").removeClass("fa fa-thumbs-down");   
            $("#likes").addClass("fa fa-thumbs-up");


            $.get('like_post/', { post_id: postId, ld: 'd' }, function (data) {
            $('#like_count').html(data);
        
        });
        
        }   
    // });
};
```

**HTML**

```
{% for d in page_obj %}
<div class="secondSection">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card" id = "cardID">
            <h4><a href="profile/{{d.created_by}}" class="userNameClick">{{d.created_by}}</a></h4>
            
            {% if request.user == d.created_by %}
            <a href="#" onclick="loadModal('{{d.id}}');" id="editLink">Edit</a>
            {% endif %}

            <p id="contents">{{d.postContent}}</p>
            <small>{{d.dateAndTime}}</small>

            <strong id = "like_count">{{ d.likes }}</strong>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" id="likes" onclick="likeOnClick('{{d.id}}');"></i>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You are using id for manipulation, it will return only first instance of HTML element. You need to  use $(this) in likeOnClick in place of id. It will work just fine.

Comment: You are assigning the **same** id to many elements. You are looping and rendering, in this loop you assign id's to elements like `id="editLink"` etc. An id is supposed to be unique in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function likeOnClick(ele, id) {
    var postId;

    postId = id;
    console.log("I went inside the function", postId);
  

    var currentClass = $(ele).attr('class');
    if (currentClass == 'fa fa-thumbs-up')
    {
     $(ele).removeClass("fa fa-thumbs-up");   
        $(ele).addClass("fa fa-thumbs-down");


        $.get('like_post/', { post_id: postId, ld: 'l' }, function (data) {
        $('#like_count').html(data);
        // $('#likes').hide();
    });

    }
    else{
        $(ele).removeClass("fa fa-thumbs-down");   
        $(ele).addClass("fa fa-thumbs-up");


        $.get('like_post/', { post_id: postId, ld: 'd' }, function (data) {
        $('#like_count').html(data);
    
    });
    
    }   
   };
```

Please try this and you need to pass this to onclick event handler.

Comment: `$(this)` won't work here.... The OP uses the onClick attribute and passes the id there. Also you should add any explanation to your question so it would be understandable.

Comment: Why it will not work. Can you explain? @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: The function `likeOnClick` will not know what is `this`. (something you can do is pass `this` in the html like `likeOnClick(this, '{{d.id}}')`)

Comment: onclick event is attached to element be it many so when user clicks $(this) will give me element which is clicked, It doesn't matter what you are passing to function

Comment: Try testing it, it will not work. Why do you expect a function to know `this` implicitly when it is called directly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228561/discussion-between-anand-shukla-and-abdul-aziz-barkat).